# Django: create view inline generic update view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I am working on Django 1.11. I have two models, the first one has a foreign key like this :

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, default=None)
    other_properties

class Owner(models.Model):
    some_property
```

I use the `generic.UpdateView` to update my Books :

```
class BookUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
model = Book
fields = ['owner']
```

This works but now I want to create an Owner from the `BookUpdateView` page, and then modify the book to set the owner property to the newly created Owner.

Is it possible to have an inline form to create an Owner inside the `BookUpdateView` ? (not in the admin pages)

Or maybe to have a separate create view for the owner which redirect to the `BookUpdateView` from where it was called. But only when it was called from there ?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create `Owner` inside your `BookUpdateView` using `form_valid()` method. This method executes when form is valid.

```
class BookUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['owner']
    def form_valid(self,form):
        owner = Owner.objects.create(define_some_property)
        .......
        return super(BookUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

You can refer to documentation  - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid